# 2d push_back doesnt save to vector values

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, stdvector, outofrangeexception

I have a 2d vector which should save x and y coordinates. Everything works as intended except saving this values to vector. What did I do wrong?

```
void Game::GetShips(Board &b)
{
    vector<vector<int>> shipCors;

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
            if (b.getSpaceValue(i, j) == SHIP) {
                cout << "X :"<< i<<"\n Y:"<<j<<'\n';
                shipCors[i].push_back(j);
              
            }
        }

    }
    cout<< shipCors.size()<<'\n';
 }
```

Comment: The outer vector has size 0, so `shipCors[i]` is always undefined behavior. Your `push_back`s don't increase the size because you apply them to the inner vectors (and because UB), not the outer one.

Comment: You need to resize the vector for the number of rows you have or `shipCors[i]` is accessing out of bounds. You could also push back a new row in the outer loop if you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Maybe a better option would be a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`? And if coordinates cannot be negative, I'd use `unsigned int` instead to reflect that fact.

Comment: "your inner vector should be a pointer to a vector" why?!? No pointer needed here

Comment: @IlanKeshet thats non-sence. `operator[]` returns a reference. push_back would work fine if `shipCors[i]` would actaully be a vector, but it isnt because `shipCors` is empty

Comment: the proposed dupe was a bout confusing a global with a local variable. I am certain there are good dupes but that wasnt one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared an empty vector

```
vector<vector<int>> shipCors;
```

So you may not use the subscript operator

```
shipCors[i].push_back(j);
```

You could write

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {

    shipCors.resize( shipCors.size() + 1 );
    for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
        if (b.getSpaceValue(i, j) == SHIP) {
            cout << "X :"<< i<<"\n Y:"<<j<<'\n';
            shipCors[i].push_back(j);
          
        }
    }

}
```

Pay attention to that as you are using the index `i` then you need to add a "row" of the vector even if the row will be empty after executing the inner for loop.

It will be even better to resize the vector initially before the for loops like

```
vector<vector<int>> shipCors;
shipCors.resize( BOARDSIZE );

for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
        if (b.getSpaceValue(i, j) == SHIP) {
            cout << "X :"<< i<<"\n Y:"<<j<<'\n';
            shipCors[i].push_back(j);
          
        }
    }

}
```

An alternative approach is to have a vector declared like

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> shipCors;
```

In this case your loop will look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
        if (b.getSpaceValue(i, j) == SHIP) {
            cout << "X :"<< i<<"\n Y:"<<j<<'\n';
            shipCors.emplace_back(i, j);
          
        }
    }

}
```

Or to keep the data sorted you can declare a set like

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> shipCors;
```

Comment: `shipCors.resize(i)` is shorter and `if ( i >= shipCors.size())`  a little safer

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is in general an incorrect approach. You need to add a new "row" in any case. I have updated my post.:)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) { shipCors.resize( shipCors.size() + 1 );` – **honestly???** In worst case you produce a bunch of totally needless re-allocations while `BOARDSIZE` is fix anyway! *Please* do `shipCors.resize(BOARDSIZE)` *before* the loop or alternatively provide appropriate size already to constructor (`vector<vector<int>> shipCors(BOARDSIZE);`).

Comment: @Aconcagua It can be done before loops but I think the approach with the vector is not good. As I pointed to it is better to use std::set.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Indeed, agree on, proposed a 1D vector of pairs myself, too, in comments to question ;) Still that code appears – let's say – pretty questionable and I wouldn't show up in an answer for a beginner who might adopt it later on... Apart from, simply calling `emplace_back` might have been more elegant.